# The gradient of a function is an alternating one-tensor

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

I'm currently reading Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* and I seem to have hit a snag in Chapter Four: *Integration on Chains*. Spivak develops tensors, vector fields, alternating tensors and differential forms. I'm okay with these ideas however he makes the claim that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then $Df(p)\in\Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I can see that the gradient of a scalar function is clearly a 1-tensor over $\mathbb{R}^n$ since it maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ but I fail to see how it is alternating (and thus in $\Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ rather than just $T(\mathbb{R}^n)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any covector is also an alternating one tensor. You should think of an alternating tensor as any tensor $ T : (T\mathbb{R}^n)^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that is invariant with respect to permutation of the p arguments up to the sign of the permutation. Since there is just one way to permute 1 argument, every one tensor is alternating.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I think I thought of this at one point but discarded the idea. Thanks!